# Grouping of Object List in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, grouping

I have something like this as output from a function [{…}, {…}, {…}], it looks like the provided code snippet.

I want to group this one by system label with the desired output above. GroupBy only gives me an Object back.

```
  [
     {
       id: 100,
       system: {id: 101, label: "BLUE", createdAt: "2019-07-30"},
       details: [{...},{...}],
       info: "Test1"
     },
     {
       id: 400,
       system: {id: 404, label: "RED", createdAt: "2019-10-30"},
       details: [{...},{...}],
       info: "Test2"
     },
     {
       id: 800,
       system: {id: 404, label: "RED", createdAt: "2019-10-30"},
       details: [{...},{...}],
       info: "Test3"
     }
   ]
```

I want to have something like this, where it's grouped by system label:

```
const after= [
  {
    color: 'BLUE',
    types: [{
             id: 100,
             system: {id: 101, label: "BLAU", createdAt: "2019-07-30"},
             details: [{...},{...}],
             info: "Test1"
           }]
  },
  {
    color: 'RED',
    types: [{
             id: 400,
             system: {id: 404, label: "RED", createdAt: "2019-10-30"},
             details: [{...},{...}],
             info: "Test2"
           },
           {
             id: 800,
             system: {id: 404, label: "RED", createdAt: "2019-10-30"},
             details: [{...},{...}],
             info: "Test2"
           }]
  }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `Array.prototype.reduce` to groupby the system label and then get the object values like

```js
const data = [
     {
       id: 100,
       system: {id: 101, label: "BLUE", createdAt: "2019-07-30"},
       shape: {id: 404, label: "round", createdAt: "2019-10-30"},
       details: [{},{}],
       info: "Test1"
     },
     {
       id: 400,
       shape: {id: 405, label: "square", createdAt: "2019-10-30"},
       system: {id: 404, label: "RED", createdAt: "2019-10-30"},
       details: [{},{}],
       info: "Test2"
     },
     {
       id: 800,
       shape: {id: 406, label: "round", createdAt: "2019-10-30"},
       system: {id: 404, label: "RED", createdAt: "2019-10-30"},
       details: [{},{}],
       info: "Test3"
     }
   ]
   
const res = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
   if(acc[item.system.label]) {
      acc[item.system.label].typen.push(item);
      acc[item.system.label].shape.push(item.shape.label);
   } else {
      acc[item.system.label] = {
         color: item.system.label,
         shape: [item.shape.label],
         typen: [item]
      }
   }
   return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(res));
```

Comment: When there ist something like system in my object, let us call it:

 shape: {id: 404, label: "round", createdAt: "2019-10-30"},

Can i add this to my end form? to get something like that (with multiple values possible)?

...
"color": "BLUE",
"shape": ["round", "square",...]
    "typen": [
....

Comment: Thanks! that works for me. You know if there is a way to count how many items are grouped together now and save in on the level of "color" and "shape" ?

Comment: You know a way?

Comment: While pushing to the object value, you just need to update the length value

Answer (score 0):

One option is using `reduce` to summarize the array and use `Map` as the accumulator.

```js
let arr = [{"id":100,"system":{"id":101,"label":"BLUE","createdAt":"2019-07-30"},"details":[],"info":"Test1"},{"id":400,"system":{"id":404,"label":"RED","createdAt":"2019-10-30"},"details":[],"info":"Test2"},{"id":800,"system":{"id":404,"label":"RED","createdAt":"2019-10-30"},"details":[],"info":"Test3"}];

let result = [...arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  let k = v.system.label;
  if (!c.has(k)) c.set(k, {color: k,types: []});
  c.get(k).types.push(v);
  return c;
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank's for the fast response!

Comment: Happy to help :)